# Unexpected results when constructing matroid representations from partial representations

Tags: combinatorics, matroids

[Edit:

There was a bug in my code: I don't need to test isomorphism between the matroid and the representation, I only need to test equality (with the vector matroid), provided I make sure the columns are in the right order.

I would still like to know whether, when we substitute non-zero elements of Fq for the *s in the partial representation, we are guaranteed to get all the projective equivalence classes of representations, and that this is true regardless of which basis we start with.

]

I'm trying to write code to find representations of matroids over Fq, using the method described in Oxley, Matroid Theory (2nd ed), p184-5.

Consider the matroid F7- whose geometric representation consists of the lines 126, 135, 147, 234, 257, 367 (ie the Fano plane with a line removed).

Relative to the basis 123, this has fundamental-circuit incidence matrix (partial representation)

```
0111
1011
1101
```

From the cycle matroid of the associated bipartite graph, we see that candidate representations will be of the form

```
100 0111
010 101*
001 1*0*
```

where we can substitute independent non-zero elements of Fq for the *s.

If I try candidate substitions for F3, I find that 4 of the possible substitutions give vector matroids that are isomorphic to F7-.

Now, suppose I do the same for the basis 145. I get

```
100 1111
010 10**
001 1**0
```

When I try substituting in elements of F3, I find that only 2 of the possible substitutions are isomorphic to F7-.

This is unexpected, because my understanding was that the different valid substitutions are representatives of the different projective equivalence classes of representations (Theorem 6.4.7, Oxley p185)

Have I got a bug in my code, or have I misunderstood?

Could it happen that for some choice of basis, there would be no valid substitutions, even though the matroid is representable using a different choice of basis?